# Migrate django1.2 project to django1.4

Tags: python, django, migration

We developed project with django version 1.2 and python 2.4. Now we want to migrate the projects into latest version (Django1.4 and python2.7).

I am very new for migration, Can anyone please advise on this.

What things do I need to take careof?
Do we need to rewrite all the code again?

Comment: Do you have a testsuite?  Have you run coverage?

Comment: yes. we have a test cases and run the coverages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we are doing (we're upgrading ~60Kloc from Django 0.97 to 1.4):

- create an upgrade branch of your code
- create a virtualenv for working on the upgrade
- download the "next" version of Django (if you prefer small steps), or the Django version you want to end up with, and place it into your own version control system (VCS).
- check out Django from your VCS to the root of your virtualenv.
- repeat until done:

  - run your testsuite (and coverage).
  - fix any problems
- add a comment in your root `__init__.py` file indicating which Django version your code works with (this will save you a lot of time one day :-)
- merge your trunk out to your upgrade branch (to get all the changes that have happened while you were working on the upgrade).
- run your testsuite, fix any problems, then check-in the merge.
- finally: reintegrate your upgrade branch back into trunk.

Now you've upgraded your code (you'll still have to plan the deployment of the upgrade, but that's another question).

ps: we store Django in our VCS so we can keep track of any changes we need to make to Django itself (especially needed if you don't want to go to 1.4, but still might need one or two fixes from that version).

Answer (score 0):

Just do it locally first. You will most certainly run into problems and then change accordingly. You don't need to change much of your code though I assume. For Django read the [Django 1.3 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/) and the [Django 1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/) and pay special attention on what was deprecated compared to previous Django version (not just 1.2, since you might have used functionalty from Django 1.0/1.1 in your app as well). In my experience these are mostly changes in settings and some minor changes in the project structure.

For Python 2.4 -> Python 2.7 I can not say much. It really depends how much old functionality you used. You will find out when you test the whole application. Might be no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtualenv, just create a new virtualenv with the versions of django/python that you want, workon this virtualenv and run your testsuite against it.

BTW, you might want to be careful with the word 'migration' whilst in a Django context. Migration normally refers to model migrations with South when you're making changes to the tables in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Python does not support backward compatibility,consider that you may get some issues on migrating to 2.7 from 2.4.